# Undefined is not an object-React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I am new to react native i am facing this error TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.items)
Another problem is it is returning me the data in an array how do i display the data as a string

[image]

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {StyleSheet,View,ActivityIndicator,FlatList,Text,TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";

export default class Source extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  title: "Source Listing",
  headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#fff"},
  headerTitleStyle: {textAlign: "center",flex: 1}
 };
};
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   loading: false,
   items:[]
  };
this.fetchRequest=this.fetchRequest.bind.this
}
FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
return (
  <View style={{
     height: .5,
     width:"100%",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
}}
/>
);
}
componentDidMount()
{
fetchRequest();
}
renderItem=(data)=>
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.name}</Text>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.email}</Text>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.company.name}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
render(){
  <FlatList
    data= {this.state.dataSource}
    ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
    renderItem= {item=> this.renderItem(item)}
    keyExtractor= {item=>item.id.toString()}
 />
  fetchRequest()
  {
    const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

    fetch('http://192.168.200.133/apptak_service/apptak.asmx/Get_Item_Master')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
             parseString(response, function (err, result) {
                  console.log(response)
             });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('fetch', err)
            this.fetchdata();
        })

 if(this.state.loading){
  return( 
    <View style={styles.loader}> 
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9"/>
    </View>
)}}
return(
 <View style={styles.container}>

</View>
)}
}

   
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   },
  loader:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   },
  list:{
    paddingVertical: 4,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   }
});
```

Basically what i am trying to do is to get data from webservices and display the app on the screen

Comment: Why do you have a FlatList outside your class ?

Comment: @ Guruparan  Just added  it in my class any else suggestion

Comment: Check your code now it doesnt have any reference to this.state.items, Can you update the correct code

Comment: @Guruparan updated the code and checked it has no reference to this.state.items

Comment: So your error shouldnt be there right ?

Comment: @Guruparan   Nope it did not have any effect on the error!

Comment: areyou getting the same error ? with this code ?

Comment: @Guruparan    Now getting this error Type Error:undefined is not an object this.fetch.request.bind

Comment: Change to this.fetchRequest=this.fetchRequest.bind(this);

Comment: @Guruparan that did not have any effect on the error

Comment: Can you check the code that you have provided, you have a fetchrequest inside the render. and please do format the code so its easy to read